# Using CERT Tapioca on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, ssl, certificate

I'm attempting to use Cert Tapioca  (http://www.cert.org/blogs/certcc/post.cfm?EntryID=203) in Virtual Box so that I can test the SSL/HTTPS security of all the sites I have browsed.

What I did is,

1. I downloaded the ova file provided in this site http://www.cert.org/blogs/certcc/post.cfm?EntryID=203 and imported in virtualbox
2. Opened Cert Tapioca
3. Changed ip address of eth0 and eth1 based on the subnet I am connected.
     eth0: from 192.168.1.x to 192.168.0.x
     eth1: from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.0.1
4. Changed ip address specified in /home/fuzz/iptables_mitmproxy.sh
5. Restarted Cert Tapioca
6. Opened web browser and go to google.com

*eth0: NAT adapter, DHCP

*eth1: Bridged adapter, Static

Using the above procedure, there's no mitmproxy traffic log has shown in mitm.sh console. Are there any steps I have missed why it didn't work? 
I read this site, [Using CERT Tapioca on VM](https://superuser.com/questions/819577/using-cert-tapioca-on-vm) which also discusses cert tapioca but I think we have different issue.
Your reply is much appreciated.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, failure to validate SSL certificates (as Tapioca can determine) happens on the **application** layer, not on the **site** layer.  So you only need to test your browser once, with one site.   And if it's a non-obscure desktop browser, you shouldn't find any problems.

First, revert Tapioca to its pristine state.  Either by reverting to a snapshot or by re-installing the OVA if you didn't make a snapshot before modifying the VM.

If the software you are testing lives in another VM (i.e. you have a two-VM test environment), then:

1. Leave the NAT-connected ethernet adapter as NAT.  With VirtualBox, this is likely "Adapter 2."   This is your internet uplink.
2. **Attach** your other (custom) network adapter to "Internal Network".  This is your internal network to provide internet connectivity to the other VM.
3. Change the network adapter of the other VM to that same "Internal Network" as well.   When you power it up, it will get an IP address, DNS, network connectivity (via NAT), and proxied web connectivity (via mitmproxy) all from the Tapioca VM.

If the software you wish to test lives on a physical WiFi-enabled device, rather than **attaching** the other network, **bridge** the adapter to the **physical** wired uplink adapter of your wireless access point.  If your test machine uses a wired network for its own internet connectivity, then you'll need an additional wired network adapter for the wireless access point.

Under most conditions, there should be no need to change IP address configuration on Tapioca.